# Bug report Python script Mail is possible?

Tags: python

I compile little addon work fine but,
Question is: Is possible make "Report a bug" button in Addon preference link to my mail?

Comment: Wouldn't make it an email link.  Rather set up a github (or  other source hosting) account and link to the issues page.  github will send an email when a new issue is posted.

Comment: @ batFINGER i put in the "tracker_url" ( bl_info )  my mail with "mailto:someone@somemail.somedomain" (Credit @Ty Martin Z). Is not a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    'name': 'Add-on',
    'category': 'User'
}

class MyAddonPreferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.operator("wm.url_open", text="Report a Bug").url="mailto:someone@somemail.somedomain"

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyAddonPreferences)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyAddonPreferences)
```

Comment: Set as the `"tracker_url"` member of the `bl_info` dictionary to generate the standard report bug button.

Comment: Ty Martin Z is good alternative, but i think batFiNGER is a better way because need only 1 line of python

Comment: Mailto link might not be a good design decision because a people use emails from web browsers and the links might not work if they don't have mail client set up. I think linking to GitHub is a better solution, but I tried to answer the question - this is how you would put it in the add-on's preferences.

Comment: @Andrea Not better, put in dictionary for the standard bug tracker button and as in MartinZ 's answer for a "Contact Me" button (eg)  (IMO not worth another answer for that point of difference MZ can edit into this one) Don't recommend using an email link to do this. (lol sidetracked  must have started this comment over 5 mins ago)